# How to move uiview on this trajectory

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiimage, anchor

Can me explane how I can rotate image use anchor point like

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vh3h5cr1mkdbfh3/ex_image2.JPG

on .m

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

on .h

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^
     {
         self.center = position;
         self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-1, 0);
         self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-5);

     }
                     completion:^(BOOL completed){

                     }];
```

When I use this code I have something like that

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v87abux9dqm4y0p/ex_image1.JPG

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a rotation transform to a layer, the rotation occurs around the anchor point.

So set the layer's anchor point to (0.0, 0.0) first.

```
self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Then you can just rotate the view and the rotation will occur around the anchor point, (0.0, 0.0).

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.1415f);
}];
```

The code will rotate the view one whole time in the way you have pictured.

You can check out [the section titled "Anchor Points Affect Geometric Manipulations" in Apple's  "Core Animation Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW17) for more information.

Comment: Set the anchor point of the view you want to animate to (0.0, 0.0) and then animate it with a rotation. It should work. I made a sample application and animated a red rectangle view in the way you described.